# Change background colour of list item from auto-generated dropdown on mouseover state

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-typeahead

I am using [twitter typeahead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) in my project.

As shown in [this example](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=typeahead-with-external-dataset) 
I need my suggestion list items to have a different background colour when I move the mouse over the list of suggestions in the dropdown. The options listed in the dropdown, do not even seem like hyperlinks (does not show the hand icon when mouse is moved over the list of suggestions in the dropdown).

From what I understand, I do not need a custom template to get this functionality working. It is built into twitter typeahead. Custom templates come in handy if I'd like to customize it beyond the basic features available.

Here's my code.

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
var users = new Bloodhound({
datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('text'),
queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace, 
limit: 10,
remote: '/some/remoteurl?name=%QUERY'
});
users.initialize();
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
highlight: true,
}, {
name: 'users',
displayKey: 'name',
source: users.ttAdapter()
});
</script>`
```

HTML is as follows.

```
`<style type="text/css">
.typeahead, .tt-query, .tt-hint {
    border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 16px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    width: 180px;
}
.typeahead {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.typeahead:focus {
    border: 2px solid #0097CF;
}
.tt-query {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
}
.tt-hint {
    color: #999999;
}
.tt-dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding: 4px 0;
    width: 180px;
}
.tt-suggestion {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    width: 180px;
}
.tt-suggestion.tt-is-under-cursor {
    background-color: #0097CF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.tt-suggestion p {
    margin: 0;
}

</style>`
```

Finally, here's my formcontrol for typeahead.

```
`<div class='container-fluid' id="searchUsersDiv">
<input type="text" placeholder="First or Last Name" class="typeahead 
tt-query" ></div>`
```

Please let me know what I am missing.

Comment: Do you need each list item to be a different colour? or do you just want to style all of the list items a different colour?

Comment: So, the dropdown opens as I type with a list of suggestions. Lets say I am moving the mouse over those options, I want the background color of the option that the mouse is on to be blue. Just as it is with the sample under the URL - http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=typeahead-with-external-dataset

Comment: The you need to add styling to `.tt-is-under-cursor` in your style sheet. That class is generated when you hover of the item

Comment: Sorry. I just noticed that I had not mentioned my css classes in the problem description. Yes. I have defined .tt-is-under-cursor on my page. I dont understand why it is never picked up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe the class isn't named *tt-is-under-cursor*...

Following [this](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#look-and-feel), it has been renamed to *tt-cursor*

> When an end-user mouses or keys over a .tt-suggestion, the class
>   tt-cursor will be added to it. You can use this class as a hook for
>   styling the "under cursor" state of suggestions.

Comment: That's it!!!!!! This solves my problem. Thankyou so much Anfuca!!! You made my day! All it took was a class definition for tt-cursor. The css class is updated as follows `.tt-suggestion.tt-cursor {
 background-color: #0097CF !important;
 color: #FFFFFF !important;
}` This solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

the class `.tt-is-under-cursor` is added when you hover an element, So all you need to do in your css is add this:

```
.tt-suggestion.tt-is-under-cursor{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: I edited the problem description and added the css classes that I had originally missed in my post. Yes. I do have this class defined. But I still dont get the background color defined under tt-is-under-cursor class.

Comment: add `!important;` you might have your styles sheets in the wrong order

Comment: @gerdi, I think you meant !important. I am not sure where I should add it but here's what I did. '.tt-suggestion.tt-is-under-cursor {
 background-color: #0097CF!important;
 color: #FFFFFF!important;
}` Still no luck

Comment: i hope you didnt code and paste my misspelling , because it is misspelt there ;)

Comment: No. I tried "!important". My css class is updated as follows:    `.tt-suggestion.tt-is-under-cursor { background-color: #0097CF!important; color: #FFFFFF!important; }` . No change.

Comment: Guys, My data is coming from remote URL.   When I view source, I do not see this class added to any option in the dropdown of typeahead. I'd expect to see the class in the dropdown when I do view source. I am not sure what is missing and why it wouldn't add this css class to the list of suggestions.

Comment: In view source you get a static view of the page, so you won't see the added classes (as they are added dynamically when you hover an element), you need to use 'inspect element'

Comment: @fatman, Thanks! I tried inspect element and hovered over the suggestion option while inspect element in chrome was open, I do not see this class. When I type, I do see that element with tt-query class blinks. But that's about it. I do not see tt-is-under-cursor anywhere. I am most certainly missing something.